# Non normality of the tangent disk topology using Baire Category Theorem

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, solution-verification, baire-category

I was trying to show that the [Moore Plane](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_plane) is a regular but not normal space.
I’m not sure of my proof of the latter property, and felt like asking if it looked alright.

We show that the disjoint closed sets $A=\Bbb{Q} \times \{0 \}$ and $B = (\Bbb{R - Q}) \times \{0 \}$ can not be separated by disjoint open sets.

Suppose that $U, V$ are open disjoint sets such that $A\subseteq U$ and $B \subseteq V$. Then for each $x\in \Bbb{Q}$ and $y\in \Bbb{R-Q}$ there exist “tangent disks” $B_x$ and $B_y$ such that $(x,0)\in B_x \subseteq U$ and $(y,0)\in B_y \subseteq V$.

Suppose the radii of $B_x$ and $B_y$ are $r_x$ and $r_y$ respectively, and choose $q_x, q_y \in \Bbb{Q}$ such that $0<q_x<r_x$ and $0<q_y<r_y$.

We’ve thus constructed a function $f : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{Q}$, $f(u)= q_u$.

Now, since $\Bbb{R} = \bigcup_{q\in \Bbb{Q}} f^{-1}(\{q \} )$ and $\{f^{-1}(\{ q\})\}_{q\in \Bbb{Q}}$ is a countable family of subsets of the real line, it follows from the Baire Category Theorem that at least one of the $f^{-1}(\{q\} )$ has non-empty interior. 
Thus let $(a,b)\subseteq f^{-1}(\{q_0\})$ for some $a<b$ and $q_0\in \Bbb{Q}$.

Now, let $(x_n)_n \subset (a,b) \cap \Bbb{Q}$ and $(y_n)_n \subset (a,b) \cap (\Bbb{R-Q})$ be two sequences in $A$ and $B$ respectively such that $x_n,y_n \to \frac{a+b}{2}$ as $n\to \infty$ (in the Euclidean topology).

Since the radii of each of the $B_{x_n}$ and $B_{y_n}$ are strictly greater than $q_0 > 0$, it must be (“geometrically”) that they eventually intersect, for $n$ large enough.

I’m not sure about that last part in particular. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The Baire category theorem does not say that one of the $f^{-1}(q)$ has nonempty interior.  Instead it says that the closure of $f^{-1}(q)$ has nonempty interior.

Comment: Of course... thank you for that observation. The proof works nonetheless though, doesn’t it? Because $f^{-1}(q)$ is dense in its closure.

Comment: Additional argument is required.  I don't think you can just pick $x_n$ rational and $y_n$ irrational just like that anymore.

Comment: I believe prof. Scott’s argument (below) is stil valid though, since, with this correction, $(a,b) \subseteq \overline{f^{-1}(q_0)}$ and thus $f^{-1}(q_0)$ is dense in $(a,b)$.

Comment: @BrianMScott Brian Scott's argument is still very helpful to show that any rational $x$ and irrational $y$ in $f^{-1}(q_0)$ would have to be at least $2q_0$ apart.  But we cannot conclude there is both such an $x$ and a $y$ at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid the slight handwaving at the end by changing your choices of tangent disks slightly, and you can simplify the last bit slightly as well. When you choose $B_x$ such that $\langle x,0\rangle\in B_x\subseteq U$, choose it to have a rational radius $q_x$ right from the start, and similar for the tangent disks at points of $B$. Then at the end fix any $x\in(a,b)\cap\Bbb Q$ and choose $y\in(a,b)\setminus\Bbb Q$ such that $|x-y|<2q_0$; then $\left\langle\frac{x+y}2,q_0\right\rangle\in B_x\cap B_y\subseteq U\cap V$.

Comment: That’s neat!! Thank you

Comment: @user622002: You’re welcome!